# Design lease mechanism of shared resource

Tags: locks, distributed-system

I have a shared resource in a database that is used by clients C1 and C2. Before the resource is read by  C1, C1 should mark the resource as leased so that C2 will know it is busy. C1 will do some work and when it is finished it will update the lease to make the resource available to C2. I am using a lease so that if the host system of Cx crashes, another C will be able to use the resource after time T.

The flow is like this:

*Start db transaction*

1. C1 reads the resource and checks the lease time to make sure `current time >= leasetime + T`
2. C1 writes timestamp of current time to lease column

*End db transaction*

3. C1 starts using the resource
4. C2 reads the resource and checks the lease time but `current time < leasetime + T` so resource is busy
5. C2 returns error
6. C1 is finished and writes `current time - T` to lease
7. C2 tries again (step 1-3) and can now lease the resource

C1 and C2 cannot communicate.

My naive implementation is to tag the resource with a timestamp from the host system to mark it as lease. When C2 tries to read the resource, it will realise that the timestamp is within the time T and that means the resource is busy. C2 will then return an error to the user and ask them to try again. This solution will not work since it depends on the system time of the host systems for C1 and C2 and that time may differ.

One thought I had was to use the database time to make the calculations of when the resource is leased or free to use. Being dependent on time still seems like a bad solution though.

How can I design this to make sure Cn will not use the resource until C1 is finished?

Comment: Your DB engine probably has something usable out of the box to handle this problem. What RDMS do you use? Anyway timeouts are a very common thing, and unless your server actively monitor the clients I don't see how to avoid them (at a reasonable cost, that is).

Comment: The way this question is worded I get the impression that C1 is different from C2 .. Cn.  And that you are only concerned with restarting C2..Cn.  But what happens if C1 crashes?  Also, C1 and C2 *are* communicating .. they are doing so through the DB.

Comment: I'm using Postgres. C1 and C2 are just different instances. I've been looking at different locking mechanisms in Postgres but they don't seem to fit my use case where the work done can take quite some time and involves network requests.

Comment: If nothing fits your Use Case it may be that you are trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.  On the other hand there may to another way to look at this.  Your problem seems similar to control of the token in token passing networks, and the mechanism used to recover the token if it is lost.  But that is just a thought.

Comment: Yes, that could very well be the case. I'm open to any suggestion on how to solve this. It's been too long since I took my Distributed Systems class :P

Comment: Sounds kind of like CAS (compare and swap) applied at DB level. I'm not well-versed in RDBMS (more the type to implement than use one) but is it possible to, in a single atomic transaction, check if a data field is the value it is expected to be and then, if it is, set to another? If so, you could have a "used" field for a resource which indicates what client is using it with, say, -1 indicating that it's unused...

Comment: ... then if C1 wants to use the resource, it tries a CAS -- making sure it's set to -1 before it marks the used field with "1" to indicate that it's using it. If the atomic transaction succeeds (the value was '-1' as expected and now '1'), C1 is now in use of the resource and other clients doing the same thing won't be able to access it (also using the CAS technique) until C1 releases it and sets it back to -1. This is typically how spinlocks are implemented.

Comment: @DrunkCoder that would be awesome. I have no idea how to do it but I'll do some more digging.

Comment: Cheers. I'm afraid I can't help you there since I suck at RDBMs stuff. But the general idea is that you model an atomic transaction that has to both compare and swap values or compare and set values. If the comparison fails against the expected value, the value doesn't get set and the whole thing fail as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

#### C1 doesn't crush case

*Start db transaction* (make sure to use [explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html)!)

1. C1 reads the resource and checks that `is_busy = false`
2. C1 writes `is_busy = true` and `leased_at` with current timestamp

*End db transaction*

3. C1 starts using the resource
4. C2 reads the resource and sees that `is_busy` is true
5. C2 returns error
6. C1 is finished and writes `is_busy = false`
7. C2 tries again (step 1-3) and can now lease the resource

#### C1 crushes case

*Start db transaction*

1. C1 reads the resource and checks that `is_busy = false`
2. C1 writes `is_busy = true` and `leased_at` with current timestamp

*End db transaction*

3. C1 crushes
4. C2 reads the resource and sees that `is_busy` is true
5. C2 returns error
6. Some separate thread/process/service/database itself (smth like [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent-source-code/)) monitors if `is_busy` was locked for too long by checking `leased_at` value. The query could be like `update table set is_busy = false where is_busy = true and leased_at < now() - interval '15 minutes'`
7. C2 tries again (step 1-3) and in 15 minutes can lease the resource

Comment: On a hunch I just check and you can schedule jobs in MSSQL, MySQL and Postgres on a timed basis from within the DB (mechanism will vary with DB product).  So it is likely the OP will be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the need for the `is_busy` column, just having the timestamp should be enough should it not? But using the database time should be fine then?

Comment: @span see my edit.